Matrices do not render in preview
Why does this example:
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & x & x^2 \\
1 & y & y^2 \\
1 & z & z^2 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

no longer render correctly, at least in preview?
$$
\begin{matrix}
1 & x & x^2 \\
1 & y & y^2 \\
1 & z & z^2 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

It appears that this primarily affects Firefox (126.0.1); preview in Chrome seems to work. Furthermore, preview in this edit view seems to be fine as well, even on Firefox.

Interestingly, the same code renders for me, see the screenshot taken in  Google Chrome, under Windows with math renderer set to HTML-CSS.
There was a similar report recently: Does this matrix look like a matrix to you? It doesn't to me

@MartinSleziak Yes, after I posted this I had the same idea... I launched Chrome, and it seems to all be fine there. So far I have only reproduced this problem using Firefox.

If it is specific to FF, perhaps the tag ([meta-tag:firefox]) is worth adding.

My Firefox (< 91.0) renders this matrix as expected. Plus, this seems to be a longstanding issue of caching/buffering particular to the SE editor preview with MathJax v2, and Ctrl + F5 usually solves the issue. This would probably be completely solved once the editor switches to the coming MathJax v4.

FWIW it works with me (Firefox 127.0).

@MartinSleziak Hi Martin. In these days many LaTeX codes not work in MathJax. Example $\,$ within of a formula, I have not a bit of space, or, for example, cases envorment not work in this website.

I have done, now, v. 126.0.6478.62 , a download on Chrome and now works correctly. Good bye.

I actually have the same problem occasionally. I'm not sure why it occurs, but usually if I reload the page enough times the problem goes away (this always works for me). The problem can occur not only in questions, but also in answers and in the tag editor.
